# PHP OOP Error - Missing argument 1 for User::__construct()

Tags: php, oop, parameters

I've been googling about this error but i can't solve it.

I have my user class in user.php file:

```
<?php

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

class User 
{

   private $usr_id;
   private $utp_id;
   private $usr_login;
   private $usr_password;
   private $usr_firstname;
   private $usr_lastname;
   private $usr_active;
   private $usr_created_usrid;
   private $usr_created_date;
   private $usr_modified_userid;
   private $usr_modified_date;

   function __construct($usr_id, $utp_id, $usr_login, $usr_password, $usr_firstname, $usr_lastname, 
           $usr_active, $usr_created_usrid, $usr_created_date, $usr_modified_userid, $usr_modified_date) 
   {
       $this->usr_id = $usr_id;
       $this->utp_id = $utp_id;
       $this->usr_login = $usr_login;
       $this->usr_password = $usr_password;
       $this->usr_firstname = $usr_firstname;
       $this->usr_lastname = $usr_lastname;
       $this->usr_active = $usr_active;
       $this->usr_created_usrid = $usr_created_usrid;
       $this->usr_created_date = $usr_created_date;
       $this->usr_modified_userid = $usr_modified_userid;
       $this->usr_modified_date = $usr_modified_date;
   }

  // some code to generate getters and setters

?>
```

And i have another file to make a login using pdo, userDAO.php:

```
<?php

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

require_once '../db/accessDB.php';
require_once '../class/user.php';

class UserDAO 
{


    public function loginUser($usr_login, $usr_password)
    {
        try {
            $pdo = AccessDB::getConnectionPDO();

            $pwd_md5 = md5($usr_password);

            $user = new User('', '', $usr_login, $pwd_md5);

            $sql = 'SELECT '
                    . ' a.utp_id, a.usr_firstname, a.usr_lastname,'
                    . ' b.utp_type'
                . ' FROM lm_user a, lm_usertype b'
                . ' WHERE'
                    . ' a.utp_id=b.utp_id AND'
                    . ' a.usr_login="?" AND a.usr_password="?" AND  '
                    . ' a.usr_active="1"  ';

            $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bindParam(1, $user->getUsr_login(), PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(2, $user->getUsr_password(), PDO::PARAM_STR);

            echo $sql;

        } catch (Exception $ex) {
            throw $ex;
        }
    }


}

?>
```

The problem is, when i want to test it, i have the following error:

[image]

What could be the problem? Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$user = new User('', '', $usr_login, $pwd_md5);`, it is not in match with the User class constructor parameters `__construct($usr_id, $utp_id, $usr_login, $usr_password, $usr_firstname, $usr_lastname, $usr_active, $usr_created_usrid, $usr_created_date, $usr_modified_userid, $usr_modified_date)`. Since all the parameters are not optionals, you need to mandatorily pass all while the object creation.

Comment: Is there any way, to set the all parameters optionals?

Comment: Use like this `__construct($usr_id=null, $utp_id=null, $usr_login=null, $usr_password=null, $usr_firstname=null, $usr_lastname=null, $usr_active=null, $usr_created_usrid=null, $usr_created_date=null, $usr_modified_userid=null, $usr_modified_date=null)`